# Matlab: Refer to multiple, non consecutive elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

In Matlab is there any way to refer to multiple, non consecutive elements in a 1 dimensional array in the same line, eg. something like:
`mean(strength(1:4,17:20))`
I want to calculate the mean of 1st to 4th elements and the 17th to 20th elements in an array called `strength` etc. Except obviously a comma wouldn't work, because that would be double indexing, as if it was a matrix, when it's 1D. Is there another symbol you could use in place of the comma to do this, or would you need another technique to do this?

Comment: Use an index vector: `strength([1:4,17:20])`. Comma optional, can be substituted with space.

Answer (score 1):

Like Andras says in his comment, you need a vector of the indices you wish to include in the calculation of the mean:

Just as you would reference the ith value of a vector with `strength(i)`, you can have a vector instead of i, which will give you all of the specified values as another vector:

```
indexVector = [1:4, 17:20];
values = strength(indexVector);
```

This will give you a 1D vector of length 8 containing values 1:4 and 17:20 of the original `strength` vector, which would allow you to use `mean(strength)`.

You can bypass writing these to variables, and just use:

```
mean(strength([1:4, 17:20]))
```